# Cannot find Oracle connector in LotusScript LCConnection

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I opened my IBM Notes application with Lotus Notes Designer 8.5. I displayed the agents list and executed an agent from this list. When doing so, I displayed the following error:

> Error 217: Error creating product object. LCConnection Error: Cannot
>   find Connector oracle

My code to display the available LCSession connectors is the following:

```
Dim conName As String
Dim conList As String
Call gLCSession.ListConnector(LCLIST_FIRST, conName)
conList = conName
While gLCSession.ListConnector(LCLIST_NEXT, conName)
    conList = conList + ", " + conName
Wend
MsgBox "The usable Connectors are: " & conList
MsgBox "Error " & Str(Err) & ": " & Error$ & " Ligne: " Erl
```

The oracle connector is not listed. Note that I'm using in my Domino server 9.0.1 FP10 x64 an Oracle client 12.1.0.2 x64 with a properly configured tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora.

Why can't I find my oracle connector? Is this agent executed on my Domino Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the agent is not executed on my Domino server. It's executed locally on my PC. This is why my server's oracle client is not accessible.

I used "NotesSession.IsOnServer" to answer my own question.